# How do I exit vim, that is within emacs term mode with evil?

Tags: terminal, vim, emacs, text-editors

I am trying to make transition from vim to emacs (specifically doom-emacs).  I was using term mode and habitually used vim in an attempt to edit another file forgetting that I was inside emacs.

I tried exiting vim with `:wq` but `:` is taken by evil being interpreted as emacs command, and while `ZZ` should work, I don't want my works to be saved in my case.

People recommended me to kill vim outside emacs or exit term mode, and that's working.  However, I am wondering whether there's a proper way to exit vim and go back to shell inside emacs term mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ZZ` works for you, but the problem is that you don't want work saved, you can use `ZQ` to quit without saving.

Comment: With an addition, that if vim is in insert mode, press `C-c C-c` to send Ctrl-C to vim to exit insert mode.

Answer (score 3):

Just turn off Evil mode so that the vim keybindings won't get interpreted globally by Emacs.

Comment: This actually was an obvious solution that I overlooked - ty sir.
Oh, and to get back to evil-mode, for me, was to hit `M-x` and type `evil-mode`